# From cUrl to Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, curl

I need to convert the following cUrl command to Python 2.7:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @myfile http://127.0.0.1/process/my/data
```

I googled for this, but I only found examples of posting fields or files, instead of sending the content of a file into the `body`of the request.

Comment: Why the -1?, can you explain it?.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, here's the answer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request("http://127.0.0.1/requests", 
    "POST", body="Here is the content of the file you want to post",
    headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    )    
print resp
```